# How can I remove a subdict in array in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I currently having a MongoDB collection which look like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$numberLong": "1234567890"
    },
    "playlists": [{
        "name": "ff",
        "author": {
            "$numberLong": "123456789"
        },
        "tracks": [{
            "name": "name1",
            "uri": "uri1",
            "duration": 100
        }, {
            "name": "name2",
            "uri": "uri2",
            "duration": 120
        }, ...
        ]
    }], ...
}
```

How can I remove the subdict that contains `{"name": "name2"}`?
I tried

```py
colletion.update_one({"_id" : 1234567890}, {"$unset" : {{"playlists" : {{{"name" : playlist}: {f"tracks.{str(track)}"} : 1}}}}})
```

but it didn't work.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator. To remove the track document with `{ "name": "name2" }` that is under playlist document (`{ "name": "ff" }`), you need to apply `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator and `arrayFilters`.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1234567890
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "playlists.$[playlist].tracks": {
      "name": "name2"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "playlist.name": "ff"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BK9g0K5_5QB)

> Pymongo

```
colletion.update_one({
  "_id": 1234567890
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "playlists.$[playlist].tracks": {
      "name": "name2"
    }
  }
},
array_filters = [
{
  "playlist.name": "ff"
}
])
```

Comment: but how can i delete it on only playlist `ff`? im sorry because the given collection didn't describe this.

Comment: Hi, done update my answer based on your requirement.